# Curly braces vs parenthesis in member initializer list

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer

Consider the following code snippet:

```cpp
struct A {
    int x;
    int y;
    A(int x, int y)
        : x(x) // initialization using parenthesis
        , y{y} // initialization using curly braces
    {}
};
```

Is there a difference between these two approaches? I couldn't find any information about this on cppreference or other websites.

For clarification: I'm **not** talking about normal initialization (e.g. `int a{3};`), I'm just referring to member initializer lists.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you can't use copy-initialization (because of no `=`), and certain subtle details involving base classes and copy elision, member initializers aren't any different from "normal" ones.

Comment: Can't imagine you could not find it https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Answer (score 1):

Cppreference mentions this [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) in its page on member initializer lists.

> The body of a function definition of any constructor, before the opening brace of the compound statement, may include the *member initializer list*, whose syntax is the colon character `:`, followed by the comma-separated list of one or more *member-initializers*, each of which has the following syntax:
>
> *class-or-identifier* `(` *expression-list(optional)* `)` (1)
>
> *class-or-identifier* *braced-init-list*  (2) (since C++11)
>
> *parameter-pack* `...`    (3) (since C++11)
>
> 1. Initializes the base or member named by *class-or-identifier* using direct-initialization or, if *expression-list* is empty, value-initialization
> 2. Initializes the base or member named by *class-or-identifier* using list-initialization (which becomes value-initialization if the list is empty and aggregate-initialization when initializing an aggregate)
> 3. Initializes multiple bases using a pack expansion

In your code, `x` is being initialized using syntax (1), which performs [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization). `y` is being initialized using syntax (2), which performs [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).